# Matplotlib-like image plotting in Vue 3 frontend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plot, plotly, chart.js

I want to transfer the functionality of a currently python based desktop app into a Vue 3 based browser app.
The application loads an image and sends it to a backend where through computer vision certain elements are detected and the position of those elements is send back to the client.

In the client I now want to display the image and overlay the positions with a scatter plot, similiar to what I would do in python with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(image)
plt.scatter(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)
plt.show()
```

It needs to be in the frontend because the user is supposed to tweak a few parameters to correct the positions all at the same time. This needs to be fast and responsive and I therefore don't want to do it in the backend and send the plot result as base64 or something like that.

I am considering using plotly or chart.js.
Are there any recommendations and experience if this could work? From the chart.js documentation I know that I can plot the coordinates and use an image as background, but is there a way to align the image coordinate system with the coordinate system of my plot in chart.js?

Are there other libraries that might be better suited?